# Can't add an attribute to a NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a  `NSManagedObject` subclass called `Record`, the attribute remaining can't be saved to core data. But others are ok.

```
@interface Record : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, assign) int remaining;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int limitCount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * finishDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * createdDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * updatedDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@end
```

Here is the debug info:

> (entity: Record; id: 0x8cc6d70
>    ; data:
>   {
>       createdDate = "2013-11-28 02:27:38 +0000";
>       finishDate = "2013-12-31 02:27:38 +0000";
>       limitCount = 12;
>       title = "Title ";
>       updatedDate = nil;
>       })

There is no attribute 'remaining' in the inserted `Record`, why?

Comment: Did you make are to update the core data model?

Comment: yes,I did update the core data model too

Comment: Try to clean the remove the app and run it again..

Comment: I've tried .but it Didn't work